# In PhpStorm, disable project incoming connection from the popuop

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

Let's say I'm working on two projects : project A and project B.

I activate "Listening for PHP debug connections" on project A.

I open a browser on project B (I don't have the intent of debugging it at this moment) PhpStorm then popups with "Incoming connection" dialog on project A, where I can :

- Map to a path (but this isn't the good project)
- Ignore

In this situation I would like to disable Listening for PHP debug connections.
But :

- The window is modal, so I can't disable Listening for PHP debug connections until it is closed
- I click ignore (or press `Esc`), but since the page make multiple requests, it popups again before I was able to deactivate Listening for PHP debug connections.

Is there a way, when PhpStorm popups, to disable the "Listening for PHP debug connections" for this project without having to wait and ignore all incoming requests first ?

Or some configuration to avoid PhpStorm for popping on another project ?

Just to be clear : obviously, I should have deactivated it on project A before opening browser on project B. So this is not the answer I call for. I would like to handle the case where I forgot to do it.

Thanks

Comment: In Settings > Debug activate "ignore external connections". Then configure correct servers for each project.

Comment: 1) `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Debug | Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` -- enable that. 2) Make sure you have configured entries at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Servers` (which you should have by now anyway as you were debugging them in the past). This way PhpStorm accepts debug connections from known sources only.